# Why does IDependecyResolver.Resolve<IUICompositionService>() method throw exception 'Catel.IoC.TypeNotRegisteredException'?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I have exception 'Catel.IoC.TypeNotRegisteredException' when I try to resolve IUICompositionService interface. I added reference Catel.Extensions.Prism and installed LoadAssembliesOnStartup.Fody from Nuget to my WPF MVVM Catel project and in App.xaml.cs in App.OnStartup() method wrote the following code:

```
var serviceLocator = new ServiceLocator();
serviceLocator.RegisterTypesUsingDefaultNamingConvention();
```

In MainWindowViewModel in command method I wrote the following code for visualizing CalibrationView view in the application MainWindow:

```
private void ShowCalibrationViewExecute()
{
    var viewModel = new CalibrationViewModel();
    var dependencyResolver = this.GetDependencyResolver();
    var uiCompositionService = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IUICompositionService>();
    uiCompositionService.Activate(viewModel, "MainRegion");
}
```

For this view there are CalibrationModel and CalibrationViewModel classes in the application. But when I press ShowCalibrationView button in MainWindow toolbar and ShowCalibrationViewExecute method calls then in line

```
var uiCompositionService = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IUICompositionService>();
```

exception Catel.IoC.TypeNotRegisteredException is thrown. The exception reports: *The specified type 'Catel.Services.IUICompositionService' is not registered or could not be constructed. Please register type before using it. The type 'Catel.Services.IUICompositionService' is not registered*. How can I correct and eliminate this error? What I'm doing wrong?

**P.S.** Now I have the followin Catel's references in my project: Catel.Core, Catel.Extensions.Controls, Catel.Extensions.Prism, Catel.Fody.Attributes, Catel.MVVM.

Comment: @Will Thanks for calling it a POS ;-)

Comment: @GeertvanHorrik Uh, umm... well, you know... I haven't used it, I'm just seeing this guy struggle this entire week trying to get the simplest thing up and running.  Maybe the docs need some love?  Or you need to take a backhoe to Catel's pit of success?  I dunno.

Comment: @Will I completely agree with everything else you said. There is a getting started guide & lots of examples. If you can't get it to work, then it's not for you. They could hire a professional that helps them set it up, but hey, that costs money and is not an option...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to implement a bootstrapper that takes care of type registration. Check out the examples in the [Examples repository](https://github.com/catel/catel.examples), it contains several prism examples.

Comment: Is there an example how to implement such a bootstrapper for type registration?